# How to get data in XML with extractvalue between NS tags

Tags: sql, oracle, xpath, plsql, extract-value

I'm working on the below xml. I need this data --> "12574017"

```
<ns0:AvlABC xmlns="http://xmlns.zzz.com/xxx/aaa/ZOZSE/POwn" 
xmlns:ns7="http://xmlns.zzz.com/xxx/aaa/ZOZ/POwn" 
xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.zzz.com/xxx/aaa/ZOZSE/COwn" 
xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.zzz.com/xxx/aaa/ZOZSE/OOwn" 
xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.zzz.com/xxx/aaa/ZOZ/COwn">
    <ns2:RequestInfoBP>
        <ns2:TypeId>sales1</ns2:TypeId>
        <ns2:Code>SALE_ORD</ns2:Code>
        <ns2:Date>2016/03/02-18:47:32</ns2:Date>
        <ns2:Id>525810007</ns2:Id>
        <ns2:MDI>
            <ns2:CINFO>
                <ns2:CUSERID/>
                <ns2:CUSERID/>
            </ns2:CINFO>
            <ns2:UINFO>
                <ns2:UpdateDate>2016/03/02-18:47:44</ns2:UpdateDate>
                <ns2:UpdateUser>936455507</ns2:UpdateUser>
            </ns2:UINFO>
        </ns2:MDI>
        <ns2:InqType>VRF_INQ</ns2:InqType>
    </ns2:RequestInfoBP>
    <ns0:Prdtype>
        <ns7:ProductKey>
            <ns7:PrdId>22627705</ns7:PrdId>
        </ns7:ProductKey>
        <ns7:DptPrd>
            <ns7:PrdId>2150905</ns7:PrdId>
            <ns7:FlsValueName>
                <ns7:FlsCharId>7125</ns7:FlsCharId>
                <ns7:FlsCharName>txn_fon_id</ns7:FlsCharName>
                <ns7:FlsValueId>9352727</ns7:FlsValueId>
                <ns7:FlsName>txn_fon_asd</ns7:FlsName>
                <ns7:FlsValueNameBI>11237118</ns7:FlsValueNameBI>
            </ns7:FlsValueName>
            <ns7:FlsValueName>
                <ns7:FlsCharId>30188302</ns7:FlsCharId>
                <ns7:FlsCharName>txn_sd_id</ns7:FlsCharName>
                <ns7:FlsValueId>12574017</ns7:FlsValueId>
                <ns7:FlsName>txn_sd_asd</ns7:FlsName>
                <ns7:FlsValueNameBI>1235858</ns7:FlsValueNameBI>
            </ns7:FlsValueName>
        </ns7:DptPrd>
    </ns0:Prdtype>
</ns0:AvlABC>
```

I can get this value with substr and instr method

```
select to_char(substr(A.DATA,instr(A.DATA,'txn_sd_id\</ns7:FlsCharName\>\<ns7:FlsValueId\>')+length('txn_sd_id\</ns7:FlsCharName\>\<ns7:FlsValueId\>'),
instr(A.DATA,'\</ns7:FlsValueId\>\<ns7:FlsName\>txn_sd_asd')-instr(A.DATA,'txn_sd_id\</ns7:FlsCharName\>\<ns7:FlsValueId\>')-length('txn_sd_id\</ns7:FlsCharName\>\<ns7:FlsValueId\>')))
value , a.* from temp_xx a
```

But "ns7" field is variable state. Because it can be sometimes <ns7:FlsValueId> sometimes like this <ns8:FlsValueId> or <ns2:FlsValueId> or <ns14:FlsValueId>  etc..

I think I must use XPath with extractvalue but I couldn't.

How Can I get this data is from variable "ns" tags with extractvalue or another way ?

```
select to_char(substr(A.DATA,instr(A.DATA,'txn_sd_id\</ns7:FlsCharName\>\<ns7:FlsValueId\>')+length('txn_sd_id\</ns7:FlsCharName\>\<ns7:FlsValueId\>'),
instr(A.DATA,'\</ns7:FlsValueId\>\<ns7:FlsName\>txn_sd_asd')-instr(A.DATA,'txn_sd_id\</ns7:FlsCharName\>\<ns7:FlsValueId\>')-length('txn_sd_id\</ns7:FlsCharName\>\<ns7:FlsValueId\>')))
value , a.* from temp_xx a
```

Comment: you should not be using instr, etc for stuff like this.  read up on local-name function for expath.  Better question is, why do you get results with different prefixes?  Sounds like a bug

Comment: First of all, thank you for your feedback and suggestions. This request triggers different server and another endpoint. unfortunately it does not have a fixed value. 
This is a huge integration. do you have a sample method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The `extractvalue()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/EXTRACTVALUE.html) is deprecated, so you shouldn't really use that.

You can use [XMLQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/XMLQUERY.html), with an Xpath that ignores the namespaces, since you don't know which one you want:

```
select xmlquery(
  '//*:FlsValueName[*:FlsCharName="txn_sd_id"]/*:FlsValueId/text()'
  passing xmltype(a.data)
  returning content).getStringVal() as id
from temp_xx a
```

| ID |
| --- |
| 12574017 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7ql0cgB6?hide=12)

If your `data` column is already an XMLType, not CLOB or varchar2, then you don't need the `xmltype()` conversion call.

The XPath looks for  a FlsValueName node which has a child FlsCharName node with value "txn_sd_id"; then gets the value from the FlsValueId node under that matched FlsValueName. All of the node references are prefixed with the `*:` wildcard namespace so they'll match any, and you don't even need to declare the namespaces as part of the XPath.

The text content of the node is returned, as a string; you can then convert that to a number by wrapping the XMLQuery in `to_number()` if you want that data type instead.

---

If you actually plan to extract multiple values then you can use [XMLTable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/XMLTABLE.html) instead. For example:

```
select x.*
from temp_xx a
cross apply xmltable(
  '//*:FlsValueName'
  passing xmltype(a.data)
  columns
    prdid number path './../*:PrdId',
    flscharid number path '*:FlsCharId',
    flscharname varchar2(10) path '*:FlsCharName',
    flsvalueid number path '*:FlsValueId',
    flsname varchar2(10) path '*:FlsName',
    flsvaluenamebi number path '*:FlsValueNameBI'
) x
```

| PRDID | FLSCHARID | FLSCHARNAME | FLSVALUEID | FLSNAME | FLSVALUENAMEBI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2150905 | 7125 | txn_fon_id | 9352727 | txn_fon_as | 11237118 |
| 2150905 | 30188302 | txn_sd_id | 12574017 | txn_sd_asd | 1235858 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eEqY68ZM?hide=24)

You can specify the data types (including sensible sizes for strings) in the `columns` clause, and I've included an example if walking back up the node tree to get the PrdId from a higher level. Nested XMLTable calls are a more useful approach if you have multiple levels each with multiple values.

Comment: Thank you ! this advice solved my problem. I'll read all your comments when I'm available. I wish you a good day